# obfuscating keystore password in JBoss 4.2.2 GA

Tags: ssl, configuration, tomcat, jboss, application-server

I've setup my jboss app-server to use SSL.  The relevant extract from my config is below.  Everything is working ok, however some people have expressed concern over the `keystorePass` attribute being in plain text.  Is there any way to obfuscate / encrypt this value?

I'm using JBoss 4.2.2.GA (on Red Hat Enterprise Edition, if that makes any difference)

```
<Connector port="8080" 
    protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
    SSLEnabled="true"
    maxThreads="150" 
    scheme="https" 
    secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" 
    sslProtocol="TLS"
    keystoreFile="/somewhere/some.keystore"
    keystorePass="somePassword"
    keyAlias="tomcat"/>
```

Edit,  To get away from the security by obscurity approach, an alternative to obfuscating this would be to not supply it at all and have tomcat prompt for the p/w on startup.  However as far as I know this isn't supported.  Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Comment: While it goes w/o saying, I'm going to say it anyway: Obfuscation / encoding of passwords provides no real security. At best, it's security-by-obscurity which is worse than no security, since it often gives a false sense of security.

Comment: @Evan Anderson, I agree, however some people get nervous at seeing passwords like that.  I've edited my question to outline a different approach, which I think is more secure, but as far as I know isn't supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible according to this wiki entry by Anil Saldhana, Lead JBoss Security Architect for JBoss:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EncryptKeystorePasswordInTomcatConnector

I have not personally implemented this, but I would imagine Anil knows the subject pretty well.

Comment: Cool!  There is also another wiki topic that explains how to do this for data source passwords:  http://community.jboss.org/wiki/encryptingdatasourcepasswords